# регулярное выражение на формат даты и обрезка 2х последних символов

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите когда есть строка из 10 символов как её отвалидировать через регулярко  в  формате dd.mm.yyyy и обрезать на 2 символа. 
К примеру:

```js
var data = '1459839599'  // два последних символа нужно обрезать тут, изначально их тут 10 , а надо что б в output было 8
var reg = /\d{2}\.{2}\.{4}/; // я так понимаю добавление точки я тут не правильно сделал? 

var output = data.replace(reg); 
console.log(output); // 14.59.8395 хотелось бы получить
```

Comment: Вообще-то ваше число из 10 цифр это количество секунд от точки старта отсчета времени, а дата для него будет не 14.59.8395, а 05.04.2016.

Comment: точно Вы были правы, а как задать нужный формат данных?

Comment: На ваш вопрос уже ответили правильно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var data = '1459839599';
var reg = /(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{0,})/;

var output = data.replace(reg, '$1.$2.$3'); 
console.log(output); // 14.59.8395
```

Answer (score 0):

**Замечание:** Хотя автор и принял ответ @greybutton, но я представлю код по мотивам своего комментария:

> Вообще-то ваше число из 10 цифр это количество секунд от точки старта отсчета времени, а дата для него будет не 14.59.8395, а 05.04.2016.

```js
function formatDate(date) {

  var dd = date.getDate();
  if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;

  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

  var yy = date.getFullYear();

  return dd + '.' + mm + '.' + yy;
}

var data = '1459839599';
var tmp = new Date(data * 1000);

console.log(formatDate(tmp));
```

Учебник https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Comment: Вы можете просто toString() метод использовать вместо formatDate(), чтобы не отвлекать от сути решения.